# "$**" wildcard specifier for text index - MongoDB in JAVA

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, mongodb-java

I want to create a text index on a collection having documents with String fields. However, this command:

```
coll_events.ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("$**", "text"));
```

However, this is returning the following error:
Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $**

I have enabled the textSearchEnabled=true in the setParameter option also.

**Edit 1:** 
I have tried the same command (it's equivalent) in the Mongo Shell given for windows as:

```
coll_event.ensureIndex({"$**": "text"})
```

**This command works fine**. So I think the problem should be somewhere in the mongodb java driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a resolved issue [JAVA-814](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-814) fixed in 2.11.2/2.12. Please update the driver to an appropriate version and then your attempts to index all string fields with `$**` should succeed.

Comment: But there is no update after this one: mongo-2.10.1.jar 
Am I wrongly searching somewhere?

Comment: There are later versions available at the download link from the [MongoDB docs Java driver page](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/).